# Transform Python code for REST in PHP

Tags: php, python, rest

Once more, I need your help. My client wishes to use a REST server for some data encryption. I have been given a code slice in Python that works. (I don't know Python so I'm gonna trust his word on that). I need to make it work in PHP.

Note: I'm using Windows and XAMPP, so any help would be appreciated if you take this into account. Also the REST server is not the real one, I don't want this public.

I am a newbie in using cURL so not sure what am I missing to make it work. Right now I have an error that states: "Could not resolve host: en.tty.is; No data record of requested type".

Here is the Python code:

```
input = urllib.urlencode({‘plaintext’: ‘some secret information’})
cyphertext = urllib2.urlopen(‘https://en.tty.is/encrypt’, input).read()
```

Here is what I've been trying to achieve with cURL 7.24.0 in PHP:

```
$url ="https://en.tty.is/encrypt";
            $data = json_encode(array('plaintext'=>$txt));

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, MY_CAINFO_PATH);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);   
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);

            $chleadresult = curl_exec($ch);
            $chleadapierr = curl_errno($ch);
            $chleaderrmsg = curl_error($ch);
            $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close($ch);

            if(!$chleadresult){ 
                echo $chleaderrmsg;die;
            }
```

Much appreciating any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be other problems with your code but at the very least your PHP and Python are not equivalent.

Read the documentation for [`urllib.urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) and [`urllib2.urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen).  These are not manipulating JSON.

Those two lines of Python are *roughly* equivalent to this PHP:

```
$input = http_build_query(array('plaintext'=>'some secret information'));
$ctx_post_input = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content'   => $input,
    ),
));
$cyphertext = file_get_contents('https://en.tty.is/encrypt', false, $ctx_post_input);
```

See [the http context options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) for the structure of `$ctx_post_input['http']`.

If you need to use CURL instead of the http stream type you can translate this to the appropriate CURL options easily.

That said, your *actual* error is `Could not resolve host: en.tty.is`, which means very simply that en.tty.is does not exist. However you say that this isn't the real server, so maybe this is a bogus error.

Comment: I replaced my cURL code with yours, and I'm getting relatively the same error :" file_get_contents(https://en.tty.is/encrypt): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. " which clearly states the domain name is valid, but the data is not the requested type. I suppose this has something to do with the content-type in header. I don't need to mandatory use cURL, i just need to get the encrypted data through this server. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @despina, sorry it should have been `'content'` not `'data'` (I wrote it from memory). See the new link to the documentation for the stream options.